# Expression in field calculator to populate a field with the same attributes as other field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, elevation

[image: I want the ALTITUDE attributes to be copied into a field called Elevation - so I can save out as a DXF and bring into Acad with the height data]I am just after a super simple expression to copy the attributes of one field directly into a new field with a different name - to export to AutoCAD with Z height data.

Comment: I am wanting to do this using Qgis field calc - I'm using: case when  "ELEVATION"  is NULL then  "ELEVATION"  is "ALTITUDE" else  "ELEVATION" end - but I only have the option to make a new field and it is populated with 0's...

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS Field Calculator, if `ALTITUDE` is the field you want to copy from, you simply write:

```
"ALTITUDE"
```

Comment: Thank you - yes - I have got this far - but when I do a save as DXF there seems to be no way to get the DXF to come into CAD with that elevation data

Comment: I think for that you need to ask a separate question. Until you do, if any of the answers here helped, you may want to mark one of them as accepted.

Comment: Indeed, that is not what you asked @CezarB you should accept the answer, as it answers your question. But there is a way: https://gisforthought.com/gis-to-cad-using-ogr2ogr-part-1-shp-to-dxf-with-contour-data/

Answer (score -2):

```
Python !ColumnName!
VB [ColumnName]
```

in field calc (ArcGIS)

Comment: Thank you very much!! I don't suppose you know the equivalent in qgis - I'm using this expression in the expression calculator case when  "ELEVATION"  is NULL then  "ELEVATION"  is "ALTITUDE" else  "ELEVATION" end........but this is only outputting a new field populated with 0....

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you wanted a QGIS answer but that's been covered now.